# Bootstrap modal: class="modal fade" causing problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get a bootstrap modal tutorial to work in my view.ejs file. But the `class="modal fade"` seems to be causing a problem. If I remove the class="modal fade" the modal permanently shows up, but if I keep it in the code nothing happens when I click on the button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal"  role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From other problems I've found other people to have, I tried to search for fade in other CSS files but cannot find anything. Also tried to add this before the code above, didn't help:

```
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
    transition: opacity .15s linear;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0); // IE9 only
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

I am new to web development and might be missing something small, please help me

Comment: are you loading `Jquery` file in your code

Comment: Its automatic for nodejs if I understand correct?

Comment: Are you loading the bootstrap JS code or just the CSS? You will need the JS for this to work. the `fade` class is added on a `click` jQuery event which fades out the modal. Use this as a test if you are not using the JS to make sure it works: `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` Once you are happy with it then download the JS and load it locally

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I might just remove fade, but its a really ugly design

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if anyone will read this, but we had this problem with a few users (not all users).

Turns out it was related to this css, which activates when you turn off window animations at the OS level:

```
    @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
        .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
            transition: none;
        }
    }
```

Removing this from bootstrap made modals work with the 'fade' class for users experiencing issue.

More on the media query here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion

Obviously removing the query is not ideal for people with reduced motion switched on.

Comment: Another option is to remove the `fade` class for users with this setting enabled:
```if (window.matchMedia(`(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)`) === true || window.matchMedia(`(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)`).matches === true) { 
  document.querySelectorAll(".fade").forEach(el => el.classList.remove("fade")) 
}```

Answer (score -1):

There might be something wrong you are doing, create your own fiddle and share it here.! 
I used your code, and its working fine! I just added the modal and fade classes to it, and it opens only when I click on the button

https://jsfiddle.net/happy2deepak/e5aukzge/

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I don't think using fiddle will give an indication of whats happening. Because we are using angular, sails, etc, so think this problem is related to more than the code?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the exact same problem right now.