# Bootstrap modal not showning only on my machine

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

My problem is simple to understand: A bootstrap modal isn't showing when it's supposed to.
As you can see in the image below, the website gets all greyed out, but it doesn't show the modal. The interesting thing is, this happens only on my machine. I've tried with Firefox, Chrome, Edge, also in Incognito mode, and nothing seems to have made a difference. However this works on anybody else's machine, including another one of my own. 
EDIT: I've tried clearing cache and using the option in the dev tools that use "no cache". Still nothing. The AJAX request returns 200, and I can see the modal HTML injected in the code, so I'd say it's working correctly.
[image: Modal not working]

Looking closely at the CSS with the dev tools, it seems that the `.modal` class still has a `display:none` attribute, and when I take that off, I can see the modal. But I shouldn't have to do that manually...

THis is the javascript that fires when you press the plus button:

```
    Start: function (id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Progetti/ElencoProgetti/Create/", //this is the location of the modal
        data: {
            id: (id == null ? 0 : id),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (id == 0) {
                $("#nuovoProgettoLabel").html("Aggiungi progetto");
            } else {
                $("#nuovoProgettoLabel").html("Modifica progetto");
            }
            $("#nuovoProgettoBody").html(data);
            //NuovoProgetto.Init();
            $("#nuovoProgetto").modal('show');
        },
        error: function () {
            Swal.fire(
                'Evento',
                'Errore durante il caricamento',
                'error'
            );
        }
    });
```

THis is the HTML of where the modal will go:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="nuovoProgetto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="title" id="nuovoProgettoLabel">Evento</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="nuovoProgettoBody"> 
        <!-- the JS injects the modal here-->
        </div>
        @*<div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE CHANGES</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
            </div>*@
    </div>
</div>
```

Pretty sure JQuery version is 331. Not so sure on bootstrap version (the senior on this says major release is 4) 
I'm still fairly new at SO so if you need anything else please let me know. I'm at a loss... Even though I've provided you with what I think is sufficient code to understand this, you probably won't be able to reproduce the issue as it only happens on my laptop.
Any clue as to what could produce this situation?

Comment: If it's just happening on your machine it's possible it's a cache issue. I can also see that the modal appears after an AJAX request, so have you checked to ensure that the AJAX request is working correctly?

Comment: Thank you for asking that.I've tried clearing cache and using the option in the dev tools that use "no cache". Still nothing.
The AJAX request returns 200, and I can see the modal HTML injected in the code, so that isn't it either.

Comment: Hello, have you found the solution to this problem? I have the same issue, not on my laptop, on a client laptop and I can't seem to find a solution

Comment: @AndreiDobrin unfortunately not. I had to reinstall the machine to solve this, but I don't think that's a real solution.

Comment: @9Snick4, Yes, it is not a solution. We have an application which is used on more than 100 computers, and it only happens on 5 of them. I cannot understand why, there is no error nowhere and it is really frustrating. I can force it to appear, but on pages where there is more than one modal, this solution doesn't work because then the second modal still doesn't appear even with the same forcing. Thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 3):

A possible cause of this issue is the computers concerned have "turn all necessary animations off when possible" under accessibility.  See this Stack overflow Question for more details.  This was the case for me.
[Bootstrap modal: class="modal fade" causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199847/bootstrap-modal-class-modal-fade-causing-problems)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31353438)

Comment: This was actually a life-saving answer for us - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$('.modal-backdrop.fade.in').remove();